# How to take a value from another dataframe if row criteria are met?

Tags: r

I am kind of new to R and try to analyse an experiment but experience difficulties right now. I got two dataframes I kind of want to combine.

[Dataframe emfix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS48B.jpg)

[Dataframe lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9fYN.jpg)

The full datasets are here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kn27vgfinjqvxmd/AABR6IAOJsU3FUr6J2XTPGxka?dl=0

`emfix` contains data from eyemovements and each row stands for one Fixation. `emfix$Fixx` and `emfix$Fixy` are the position of the eyes. This was a reading experiment and different `emfix$Stimulus` contain a different number of lines with different borders on the y axis. These borders are in `lines$minlimit`and `lines$maxlimit`.

I now want to determine the line number of each fixation in `emfix` with the help of `lines`. What R has to do is grab the information of `emfix$Stimulus`and `emfix$Fixy`and check whether they match with `lines$Stimulus`and are in between `lines$minlimit`and `lines$maxlimit`. Then it has to return the value of `lines$LineNumber`of that row that matches to a new column of `emfix$LineNumber`.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Best wishes,
Dominik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd propose to use an SQL-join like mechanism (although it might happen to be quite resource-consuming).
My pro's:

- it's relatively easy to debug and test
- it's shouldn't be affected if a single `emfix$Fixy` point falls between several `lines$minlimit` and `lines$maxlimit` pairs

My example code:

```
    emfix <- data.frame(fixy = c(0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,10), stimulus = c("a","a","a","b","b"))
    lines <- data.frame(lines = c(1,2,3,4,5), maxlimit = c(1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1), minlimit = c(0,1,2,3,4), stimulus = c("a","a","a","b","b"))    
    mer <- merge(x = lines, y = emfix, by = "stimulus")    
    mer[which(mer$fixy <= mer$maxlimit & mer$fixy >= mer$minlimit),] # prints out complete lines OR    
    mer[which(mer$fixy <= mer$maxlimit & mer$fixy >= mer$minlimit), c("stimulus", "lines", "fixy")]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my problem (surprisingly easy)! I was thinking about merge didn't have the idea! Thanks!